# Link VowpalWabbit C library in an existing C project

Tags: c++, c, makefile, dynamic-linking, vowpalwabbit

We have an existing C project in which we want to use vowpal wabbit. We are able to generate the executable binary of the project without vowpalWabbit and that run fine as well. But when we link vowpalWabbit with the existing project the generated binary is somehow corrupted. We are able to compile and run a standalone program by linking vowpal wabbit library.

We are trying to link VowpalWabbit with the existing project's makefile in the following manner:

```
CFLAGS      = -g -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-compare
CXXFLAGS    = -g -Wall -O2 -std=gnu++11 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-compare

VW_LIBS = $(VW_HOME)/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/libvw.la $(VW_HOME)/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/liballreduce.la 

SRC = $(BASE_DIR)/$(VW)/$(SRC_DIR)
SRC_FILES =$(SRC)/vw_predict_test.cpp

ALL_SRC_FILES =  $(SRC_DIR)/test_main.cpp \
            $(SRC_FILES) 


bin_PROGRAMS = test 

##  binary
test_SOURCES = $(ALL_SRC_FILES)
test_LDADD = $(VW_LIBS) -lthriftnb -lthrift -levent -lpthread -lm -lssl -lstdc++  
test_CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS)
test_CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS)
```

this makefile generates corrupted executable. When we do ldd on that executable we get the following message :

```
$ ldd test
        not a dynamic executable
```

Please guide how can we link vowpalWabbit in our executable.

EDIT : For a better understanding, pasting the snapshot of our MakeFile.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}

CFLAGS      = -g -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-compare
CXXFLAGS    = -g -Wall -O2 -std=gnu++11 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-compare

BASE_DIR    = .
# Dependencies defined here
COMMON      = common
COMMONS_REPO    = @COMMONS_REPO@
ANALYTICS_REPO  = @ANALYTICS_REPO@

CRYPT           = $(COMMONS_REPO)/crypt
SSSTORE     = $(COMMONS_REPO)/datastore/lib/C
PREDICT     = $(ANALYTICS_REPO)/predict
SRC_DIR     = src
LIB_DIR     = lib
INCLUDE_DIR     = include 
OBJDIR      = build
SCRIPT_DIR      = scripts
CONF_DIR    = conf
VW      = $(ANALYTICS_REPO)/vw

VW_LIBS = $(VW_HOME)/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/libvw.la $(VW_HOME)/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/liballreduce.la


# install directories
TARGET_DIR      = /mytest
LOG_DIR         = /mytest/processor/logs
TARGET_DATA_DIR     = /mytest/processor/data/processor/trafficking
TARGET_CONF_DIR     = $(TARGET_DIR)/conf
TARGET_LIB_DIR      = $(TARGET_DIR)/libs
TARGET_BIN_DIR      = $(TARGET_DIR)/bin
TARGET_SCRIPTS_DIR  = $(TARGET_DIR)/scripts
TARGET_LOG_DIR      = $(LOG_DIR)/{cores,processor/{app,archive,concat_logs}}

##  Thrift autogeneration
THRIFT_EXEC     =  /usr/local/bin/thrift

CC= /usr/local/bin/qrintf gcc
CXX= /usr/local/bin/qrintf g++

PROTOCOL_DIR    =../resources/schema
TEST_THRIFT =$(PROTOCOL_DIR)/test.thrift

GENERATED_THRIFT=generated/thrift

$(GENERATED_THRIFT)/gen-cpp/testservice.cpp: $(TEST_THRIFT)
    mkdir -p $(GENERATED_THRIFT)
    $(THRIFT_EXEC) -o $(GENERATED_THRIFT) --gen cpp $(TEST_THRIFT)

CRYPT_SRC_FILES = $(CRYPT)/src/utils.cpp $(CRYPT)/src/keyPair.cpp $(CRYPT)/src/keystore.cpp

DATASTORE_SRC = $(BASE_DIR)/$(SSSTORE)/$(SRC_DIR)

## Protobuf autogeneration
PROTOBUF_INSTALL_DIR  =  /usr/local
PROTOBUF_EXEC    =  $(PROTOBUF_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/protoc
COMMON_PROTO    =  common.proto

PROCESSOR_SCRIPT_FILES = $(SCRIPT_DIR)/test_logs.pl 

PROCESSOR_CONF_FILES = $(CONF_DIR)/server.tmpl

SCHEMA_FILES = $(SSSTORE)/src/avro.click.schema 

CI_SCRIPTS_DIR = scripts/CI

GENERATED_PROTOBUF=$(DATASTORE_SRC)/generated/proto
GENERATED_PROCESSOR_LOG_PROTO=generated/proto

$(GENERATED_PROTOBUF)/common.pb.cc: $(DATASTORE_SRC)/$(COMMON_PROTO)
        mkdir -p $(GENERATED_PROTOBUF)
        $(PROTOBUF_EXEC) --proto_path=$(DATASTORE_SRC) --cpp_out=$(GENERATED_PROTOBUF) $(DATASTORE_SRC)/$(COMMON_PROTO) 

BUILT_SOURCES = $(GENERATED_THRIFT)/gen-cpp/testservice.cpp $(GENERATED_PROTOBUF)/common.pb.cc 


EDGE_DEFAULT_INCLUDES = -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(BASE_DIR)/$(CRYPT)/$(INCLUDE_DIR) \
                        -I$(BASE_DIR)/$(SSSTORE)/$(INCLUDE_DIR) \
                        -I$(BASE_DIR)/$(PREDICT)/$(INCLUDE_DIR) \
                        -I$(BASE_DIR)/$(COMMON)/$(INCLUDE_DIR) \
                        -I/usr/local/include/thrift \
                        -I$(GENERATED_THRIFT)/gen-cpp -DOPTIMIZE_RESPONSE_FOR_SIZE=1 \
                        -I$(PROTOBUF_INSTALL_DIR)/include/ \
                        -I$(GENERATED_PROTOBUF) -g -I${GENERATED_PROCESSOR_LOG_PROTO} -g

if CENTOS64
INCLUDES = $(EDGE_DEFAULT_INCLUDES) -I /usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
endif

if CENTOS
INCLUDES = $(EDGE_DEFAULT_INCLUDES) -I /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
endif

if DEBIAN64
INCLUDES = $(EDGE_DEFAULT_INCLUDES) -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include 
endif

if DEBIAN
INCLUDES = $(EDGE_DEFAULT_INCLUDES) -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
endif


COMMON_SRC = $(BASE_DIR)/$(COMMON)/$(SRC_DIR)
COMMON_SRC_FILES = $(COMMON_SRC)/mytest_config.c $(COMMON_SRC)/mytest_utils.c 

DATASTORE_SRC_FILES = $(DATASTORE_SRC)/data_store.c

SRC = $(BASE_DIR)/$(VW)/$(SRC_DIR)
SRC_FILES = $(SRC)/predict_model.c $(SRC)/predict_variable_util.c  $(SRC)/vw_predict_test.cc

ALL_SRC_FILES =  $(SRC_DIR)/test_main.cpp \
            $(COMMON_SRC_FILES) $(DATASTORE_SRC_FILES) $(SRC_FILES) $(CRYPT_SRC_FILES) 


bin_PROGRAMS = test 

bindir = build

#all-local: $(bin_PROGRAMS)
#   rm -rf *.o

##  binary
test_SOURCES = $(ALL_SRC_FILES)
test_LDADD = $(VW_LIBS) -lthriftnb -lthrift -levent -lpthread -lm -lssl -lglib-2.0 -lstdc++ -lz -luuid -lcrypto -lcitrusleaf -lavro -lrt -lprotobuf
test_CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS)
test_CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS)

clean-local:
    -rm -rf $(GENERATED_THRIFT)

install: test
    mkdir -p $(TARGET_BIN_DIR) $(TARGET_CONF_DIR) $(TARGET_SCRIPTS_DIR) $(TARGET_DATA_DIR) $(TARGET_LOG_DIR)
    install -t $(TARGET_BIN_DIR) test
    install -t $(TARGET_BIN_DIR) $(CI_SCRIPTS_DIR)/*
    install -t $(TARGET_CONF_DIR) $(PROCESSOR_CONF_FILES) $(SCHEMA_FILES)
    install -t $(TARGET_SCRIPTS_DIR) $(PROCESSOR_SCRIPT_FILES)
```

EDIT2: As suggested we are now using `vw_predict_test.cpp` and compiling using g++ . We have `liballreduce.a`, `libvw.a`, `libvw_c_wrapper.a` libraries we wanna link to our executable, so we did the following :

```
test_SOURCES = $(ALL_SRC_FILES)
test_LDADD = -lthriftnb -lthrift -levent -lpthread -lm -lssl -lglib-2.0 -lstdc++ -lz -luuid -lcrypto -lcitrusleaf -lavro -lrt -lprotobuf -lboost_program_options $(VW_HOME)/vowpalwabbit/.libs/liballreduce.a  $(VW_HOME)/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.a  $(VW_HOME)/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw_c_wrapper.a 
test_CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) 
test_CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS)
```

now we are getting boost exceptions like :

```
/vowpalwabbit/.libs/libvw.a(search_sequencetask.o): In function `SequenceSpanTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_sequencetask.cc:(.text+0x13f6): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
search_sequencetask.cc:(.text+0x142e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

We added -lboost_program_options in LDADD as well which didn't work.

Comment: There's no build rule for "test" in the Makefile you've posted - hard to say why it's not building it correctly if we can't see how it's built.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I have pasted the snapshot of MakeFile in the post. Please have a look.

Comment: There's still no build rule for "test" and most of what you've included doesn't look at all related either - all you need to include is a [mcve] from your Makefile that shows us how you're building "test".

Comment: Be aware that `vw` is a C++ library, as such its external symbols are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).  To compile and/or link with it, you would need to use only `g++` (or `clang++`)  not `gcc` (or `cc`) even on your own C code.

Comment: @arielf I have edited the post(EDIT2) and did what you suggested, now we are trying to link .a files of VW but getting some boost exceptions, please have a look and guide

Comment: Unfortunately boost doesn't guarantee backwards binary compatibility and is notorious for breaking binary compatibility frequently.  You need to make sure you build both your `test` program and the `vw` library with exactly the same boost versions.  I would also recommend building both with exactly the same compiler/linker toolchain (be it either clang or gcc) just to be safe.

Comment: You may also need to change the `-std=...` flags to be compatible with `vw` Makefile which uses:  `-std=c++0x`.  Mixing different standards might also cause compatibility issues between modules/libs.  Looks like this tool can help determine binary compatibility:  https://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/

Comment: @arielf we have compiled `VW` and `test` with same compiler using -std=c++0x as standard.

We are able to build the rpm as well. But when we install the rpm we get following error : 

`rpm -ivh test-1.0.0-20170330_12_59_40.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
 liballreduce.so.0()(64bit) is needed by test-1.0.0-20170330_12_59_40.x86_64
 libvw.so.0()(64bit) is needed by test-1.0.0-20170330_12_59_40.x86_64
 libvw_c_wrapper.so.0()(64bit) is needed by test-1.0.0-20170330_12_59_40.x86_64`

We have done static linking as mentioned in the post, then why is it asking for .so files?

Comment: We are able to make the binary properly and when we do `ldd` on that binary we can see VW's so files in there. But when we try to create a rpm out of it and install that rpm, then we are getting above error. Please help.